# Python String parsing: filenames with spaces

Tags: python, windows, filenames, string-parsing

This probably isn't the most common filename parsing problem, but I have a program that displays a list of files in the following format:

```
Filename.ext Location
```

Some examples would be

```
sampleFile.jpg C:\Images\my jpgs
another file.bmp C:\Images\myBmps
```

The filename and the location is separated by a single space. As shown, I can have spaces in my filename.

I want to extract the filename from each line but can't seem to find a good way to do so.
I thought of searching the index of a particular character then extract substring from 0 to (index - offset), where offset is the number of characters I should go back. But I don't think there is a character that I could search on that will guarantee a hardcoded offset would work.

Comment: Batch?  Powershell?  Cygwin?  PHP?  What is your question in reference to?

Comment: "But I don't think there is a character that I could search on that will guarantee a hardcoded offset would work." is really important.  If you can't define a rule, then we can't either.

Comment: @S.Lott, you're not restricted to following the same approach.

Comment: Why won't : work as the character to index based off of? Don't all locations in your file start with drive :?

Comment: It appears that I'm not able to check back often enough.  I apologize for being too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably uses a regex for grabbing anything that started with a drive letter to the end of the line, something like:

```
 import re
 matchWinPaths = re.compile("^.*([A-Z]:\\.+$)")
```

then match each line with

```
 matches = re.match(line, matchWinPaths)
 winPath = matches.group(1)
```

Comment: Any drive letter sounds like a good plan. I have not found a way to produce any input that does not include a drive letter at the front of the path.

Comment: @Keikoku: "But I don't think there is a character that I could search on that will guarantee a hardcoded offset would work"?  So the "[A-Z]:" would actually work?  Can you the question to clarify this?  It's still a little confusing what the exact rules for your input file are.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have periods (`.`) in your file names, other than at the end right before the extension? If not, you should be able to parse something like this:

```
1 find first instance of '.'
2 step to the next space
3 that space is the delimiter between file name and location
```

Comment: Since periods is a valid filename character, it is possible that a filename with a period may appear on the list. It was a good try though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have distinct location, eg C:\ , D:\ etc, you can just split on these characters

```
import re
f=open("file")
for line in f:
    print re.split("[C-Z]:",line)[0]
f.close(0
```